# GitHub Pages and DNS Records

Tags: domain-name-system, github

I want to have my new site located at [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/), but unfortunately I've been using an email account with the domain I want to point to GitHub.

So, I have this paid hosting where I'm receiving my emails, my domain name registered at GoDaddy, and I want to keep it that way. I just need to have the Website content located at GitHub.

How would I change the DNS Records so this setup works? That is, domainname.com and all its subdomains pointing at GitHub, but I would still be able to receive my emails, because they are located at my paid hosting.

Thanks!

PS: According to [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) article, I need to change the A record to the IP they give me, but I don't know how to do the email setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the A record of your domain to GitHub-IP and the MX Record to your e-mail Provider.

Example:

```
domainname.com IN A 207.97.227.245
domainname.com in MX 10 <name of your e-mail providers server>
```

This should be all to do.

Comment: Hey there! You see, I did something similar, but GoDaddy also declares a Points to field for the MX record. Every other example I've seen online only uses the host field. Anyways, I declared a "mail" A Record with the e-mail server's IP, and the MX Record as follows: Priority=0, Host=mail, Points to=mail.mydomain.com. I tried sending myself an e-mail today, but it did not arrive. I didn't even get an error message or anything. In your example, and according to these fields GoDaddy gives me to fill, where would I put the e-mail server's IP address? In Points to? Any leads? Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh! Miserable GoDaddy and their confusing naming. It happens that you need to set up the Host as @, and Points to as mail.mydomain.com. I even just received the test e-mail I sent yesterday. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, and remember I set an A Record for mail.

Comment: [GitHub now recommends](http://help.github.com/pages/) using IP address `204.232.175.78` in your A record.